# Discern "ongoing" notifciations in AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, notifications

In the new JB-4.3 NotificationListenerService, each StatusBarNotification-object has a `isOngoing()` method to see if it's a persistent notification. Is the same also possible with the AccessibilityService? I've cast the event to `Notification`, but this is equivalent to `sbn.getNotification()` (and therefore doesn't have an `ongoing`property).

Also, is there a way to clear existing status bar notifications using the `AccessibilityService`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [StatusBarNotification.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr2-release/core/java/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.java), `isOngoing()` just looks at the flags:

```
public boolean isOngoing() {
    return (notification.flags & Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT) != 0;
}
```

So you can do this too.

There's no way to clear notifications using an accessibility service—that's why the NotificationListenerService was created. :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for your answer! I would have never thought to look at the `StatusBarNotification`-source as I was sure that it was doing some 4.3-only-magic :-)!